# Does ActionMailer :sendmail work in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 app that I'm trying to deploy to production on heroku.  I'm using ActionMailer :sendmail to send emails from the app.  :sendmail works fine in development but the app does not seem to send out emails in production.  The configuration for config/environments/development.rb is

```
Controlsafe::Application.configure do
  ........ 
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost:3000'}
  config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-reply@controlsafe.com'}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  .......
end
```

And for config/environments/production.rb is

```
Controlsafe::Application.configure do
  ........ 
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'controlsafe.com'}
  config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-reply@controlsafe.com'}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  .......
end
```

I'm not sure why the app is not sending out emails when it does fine in production.  Does :sendmail even work in production?  Or do I have to go with SMTP?

It would be awesome if anyone can provide some insight!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Heroku you need to use an external SMTP service

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp